# make text disappear after clicking another clickable object

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making an escape room for my website, I have made a few clickable objects that will display a text. My question is, how do I make text go away after clicking on another clickable item? Everything else in my code works just how I like it except for the text part. Please help

Here is what I have so far.

```js
var hasBluekey = false;
var doorknob = "locked"
var comboLock = "locked"



function tryDoor() {
  console.log("You clicked the door");
}

function lookhelp() {
  console.log("You clicked on help");
  let text = "Who needs help?";
  document.getElementById("thehelp").innerHTML = text;

}

function lookClue() {
  console.log("You clicked on the clue");
  let text = "Hmm, there are letters and numbers circled...";
  document.getElementById("theclue").innerHTML = text;
}

function moveTable() {
  console.log("You clicked on the table");
  let text = "You carefully move away the table with the broken vase";
  document.getElementById("thetable").innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementById("table").style.display = "none";
}




function tryDoorknob() {
  console.log("You clicked the doorknob")
  if (hasBluekey == true) {
    doorknob = "unlocked";
    alert("The doorknob is now unlocked");
    checkRoom();
  } else {
    alert("You need a key");
  }


}

function tryComboLock() {
  console.log("You clicked the combo lock");
  var comboTry = prompt("You enter the combination...");
  if (comboTry == "AV70") {
    comboLock = "unlocked";
    alert("The combination was correct");
    checkRoom();
  } else {
    alert("The combination was incorrect");
  }

}

function grabBluekey() {
  console.log("You clicked the blue key");
  hasBluekey = true;
  alert("You picked up the key");
  document.getElementById("bluekey").style.display = "none";

}

function checkRoom() {
  if (doorknob == "unlocked") {
    if (comboLock == "unlocked") {
      document.getElementById("next").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      alert("You push on the door but still need a combination");
    }
  } else {
    alert("You try to turn the door knob but is still locked");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="room">
    <img id="door" src="door1.png" onclick="tryDoor()">
    <img id="doorknob" src="doorknob1.png" onclick="tryDoorknob()">
    <img id="comboLock" src="comboLock.png" onclick="tryComboLock()">
    <img id="bluekey" src="blue_key.png" onclick="grabBluekey()">
    <img id="clue" src="clue.png" onclick="lookClue()">
    <img id="help" src="help.png" onclick="lookhelp()">
    <img id="bloodMark" src="bloodMark.png">
    <img id="table" src="table.png" onclick="moveTable()">
    <img id="window" src="window.png">
    <p id="thehelp"></p>
    <p id="theclue">
    </P>
    <p id="thetable"></p>
  </div>
  <button id="next" onclick="window.location.href 
        ='room2.html';">Proceed</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which text are you hoping to disappear? It's not too clear

Comment: when i click on the clue (onclick="lookClue() ), it is gonna say, "There is a clue", so once I click on another object (example, the table), I want the first text from the clue to disappear and make the text from the table appear

Comment: Could you not just make the text appear based upon the status of a radio button?  Only one display at a time would then be visible.

Comment: Not sure how to code that.....I am just now getting back into coding after  it being many years later

Answer (score 0):

Your request seem impossible with an easy answer because you are displaying the text with `console.log()` I don't think it is possible to update individual lines of output in the console. It is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation. Your easy way out is to display the message or text in a separate element and update that element with the latest text as required. Here is how your code should look like now.

in your html add this code where you want the message to be displayed and style it however you want

```html
  <p id="text_message"></p>
```

And in your javascript code you should replace the `console.log("your message");` to this `text_message.innerHTML = "your message";`

```js
var hasBluekey = false;
var doorknob = "locked"
var comboLock = "locked"



function tryDoor() {
text_message.innerHTML = "You clicked the door";
}

function lookhelp() {
text_message.innerHTML = "You clicked on help";
  let text = "Who needs help?";
  document.getElementById("thehelp").innerHTML = text;

}

function lookClue() {
text_message.innerHTML = "You clicked on the clue";
  let text = "Hmm, there are letters and numbers circled...";
  document.getElementById("theclue").innerHTML = text;
}

function moveTable() {
text_message.innerHTML = "You clicked on the table";
  let text = "You carefully move away the table with the broken vase";
  document.getElementById("thetable").innerHTML = text;
  document.getElementById("table").style.display = "none";
}




function tryDoorknob() {
text_message.innerHTML = "You clicked the doorknob";
  if (hasBluekey == true) {
    doorknob = "unlocked";
    alert("The doorknob is now unlocked");
    checkRoom();
  } else {
    alert("You need a key");
  }


}

function tryComboLock() {
text_message.innerHTML = "You clicked the combo lock";
  var comboTry = prompt("You enter the combination...");
  if (comboTry == "AV70") {
    comboLock = "unlocked";
    alert("The combination was correct");
    checkRoom();
  } else {
    alert("The combination was incorrect");
  }

}

function grabBluekey() {
  text_message.innerHTML = "You clicked the blue key";
  hasBluekey = true;
  alert("You picked up the key");
  document.getElementById("bluekey").style.display = "none";

}

function checkRoom() {
  if (doorknob == "unlocked") {
    if (comboLock == "unlocked") {
      document.getElementById("next").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      alert("You push on the door but still need a combination");
    }
  } else {
    alert("You try to turn the door knob but is still locked");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p id="text_message" style="background-color:grey;color:white;"></p>
  
  <div id="room">
    <img id="door" src="door1.png" onclick="tryDoor()">
    <img id="doorknob" src="doorknob1.png" onclick="tryDoorknob()">
    <img id="comboLock" src="comboLock.png" onclick="tryComboLock()">
    <img id="bluekey" src="blue_key.png" onclick="grabBluekey()">
    <img id="clue" src="clue.png" onclick="lookClue()">
    <img id="help" src="help.png" onclick="lookhelp()">
    <img id="bloodMark" src="bloodMark.png">
    <img id="table" src="table.png" onclick="moveTable()">
    <img id="window" src="window.png">
    <p id="thehelp"></p>
    <p id="theclue">
    </P>
    <p id="thetable"></p>
  </div>
  <button id="next" onclick="window.location.href 
        ='room2.html';">Proceed</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to replace the alert. I followed a tutorial on youtube but I want to use a different way to display the text, and then once another clickable object is clicked on then another text appears and the old text goes away

Comment: To replace the alert you have to create a custom element that can be easily modified with innerHTML and replace the message in the element according with innerHTML when required

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use ANSI escape codes -- they are really useful for formatting text in a terminal after it's been printed. For this you would want to use [**cursor controls**](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797#cursor-controls) and [**erase functions**](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797#erase-functions). these are from [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797), which was very helpful for a project I made a while ago. Not all of them work on every platform (e.g. replit, not sure if anyone actually uses that though) but overall it's a good system.

example:

```
console.log("normal text");

//bold, red foreground
console.log("\u001B[1;31m");

console.log("edited text");
```

(example from the tutorial)

I'm bad at making examples, but I found the two aforementioned sections to be good for quick reference. To truly comprehend how to use it, I suggest that you read through the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks, I am using notepad++, can you possible provide me on how to use the code?